# LibreOffice royally screwed my docx file, now I have a SAXParseException, not even the column number is correct

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, xml

Ok, so I have last edited a file with LibreOffice 4 back in October. In the meantime I have upgrade to LibreOffice 5 (which I regret, because the UI has gotten much worse, different story). This doesns't open the file any longer, I seriously get an *XML parser exception*:

[image]

I have a version of that file I might recover from git history which means I lose two hours of editing. So can I fix this file somehow?

I see here https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/58321/error-when-trying-to-open-document/ that I can unzip the .docx and open the particular files. Only... that marvellous SAX parser is giving me non-sense positions. Line 2, Column 68720 is this:

[image]

(cursor underlined). Only a bit early I find some `hAnsi` attribute, but in no way is it "duplicate" or "redefined". Those `hAnsi: Font-name` entries are all over the place, so I have little hope that removing a random instance somewhere repairs the file.

Let's say I do remove that `hAnsi` thing, and I save the file. How do I get back from the extracted zip archive to docx? Do I just create a regular zip and rename the result?

Comment: Yes;  You should recover a known valid uncorrupted copy of the file to resolve your problem.

Comment: I restored a previous version I had backup'ed. Lost probably two hours worth of editing.